# Indentation between pages in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am using UIScrollView with paging enabled. My code is based on [PageControl example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007795).

Pages in UIScrollView stay close to each other. But I need to add some space between pages (like when you browsing photos in Camera Roll). Is there any way to add some horizontal indentation between pages?

Answer (score 0):

Find the method `loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page` in [PhoneContentController.m](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Listings/Classes_iPhone_PhoneContentController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007795-Classes_iPhone_PhoneContentController_m-DontLinkElementID_20) and look at this line:

```
frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
```

It is setting the x position of the content frame within the scrollView by the width of the content * the number of the page. So if you want to add a gutter between content you could do something like:

```
int xOffset = 20;
frame.origin.x = (frame.size.width * page) + xOffset;
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this way. But ScrollView doesn't stops properly on pages when scrolling. And the second page displays shifted to the right by 20 points;

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the scrollView's frame wider so it extends by gap/2 pixels out to the left and right of the screen.

```
CGFloat gap = 20.0; //20 pixels spacing between pages
CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
frame.size.width += gap;
frame.origin.x -= gap/2;
scrollView.frame = frame;
```

You then add the content viewcontroller's like normal, centered and filling the screen, so make sure to properly offset them by gap/2 in `loadScrollViewWithPage:`

**Edit:** if you are targeting iOS 6 only, you could instead use a UIPageViewController with UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll and using the UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey option.